# ¿Cómo corregir este error invalid property value?

Tags: html, css

La imagen no me carga, entonces cuando voy a revisar en elements y style, me sale un cartel con invalid property value, en el tutorial si funcionaba

ESO TENGO EN LO DE LA IMAGEN, ESTA HECHO EN UN HEADER LA CLASE heroo.
cuestion que al momento de fijarme, me salia el problema este que es invalid property value

```
.heroo{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 600px;
    max-height: 800px;
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr;
}

y le agregue al heroo::before
    

.heroo::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(180 deg, #0000008c 0%,#0000008c 100%), url("../imagenes/paisaje1.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 80%, 50% 95%, 0 80%);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu propiedad `background-image:` no está bien y es lo que da error.

No sé que quieres hacer ya que no lo pones por ningún lado.
De todas formas, para que funcione cambia `background-image: linear-gradient(180 deg, #0000008c 0%,#0000008c 100%), url("../imagenes/paisaje1.jpg");`

por

`background-image: url("../imagenes/paisaje1.jpg"), linear-gradient(to bottom, #0000008c, #0000008c);`